# How to avoid the restarting the values on startActivity from a activity?

Tags: android

I am working on a filter activity in which there are 3 images at the bottom. By default, image 3 will be selected as it is the last one that will be clicked.

This same activity contains Latitude and Longitude which will be sent to next activity to fetch nearby locations.

The problem that I am facing is that among those 3 images when I select a filter for Image 1 and select the image 2, the activity gets restarted and because of this, the lat and long values are reset to 0.0 and 0.0 respectively.

Code -

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements FiltersListFragment.FiltersListFragmentListener, EditImageFragment.EditImageFragmentListener {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.camera_activity_main_filter);

        instagramFilterIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);

        ButterKnife.bind(this);

        getBundleValues();

        loadImage();

        setupViewPager(viewPager);

        setBitmap(originalImage);

        ivSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                saveImageToGallery();
                startingActivtity();

            }
        });


        ivClose.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                saveImageToGallery();
            }
        });
    }

    double latitude,longitude;
    private void getBundleValues() {
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

        if (extras != null) {
            if (extras.containsKey("image")) {
                Log.e("image", extras.getString("image"));

                editingImage = extras.getString("image");

                imgFile = new File(extras.getString("image"));
                originalFile = imgFile;

                if (imgFile.exists()) {
                    Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());
                    //Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), myBitmap);
                    originalImage = myBitmap;
                }
            }
            if(extras.containsKey("PESDK")){
                initiated=extras.getBoolean("PESDK");
            }
            if(extras.containsKey("Latitude")){
                latitude=extras.getDouble("Latitude");
                Toast.makeText(this, "lat"+latitude, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            if(extras.containsKey("Longitude")){
                longitude=extras.getDouble("Longitude");
            }
            if (extras.containsKey("Filters")) {
                filters = extras.getBoolean("Filters");
                instagramFilterIntent.putExtra("Filters", filters);
            }

            if (extras.containsKey("Image1")) {
                files[0] = extras.getString("Image1");
                instagramFilterIntent.putExtra("Image1", files[0]);
            }
            if (extras.containsKey("Image2")) {
                files[1] = extras.getString("Image2");
                instagramFilterIntent.putExtra("Image2", files[1]);
            }
            if (extras.containsKey("Image3")) {
                files[2] = extras.getString("Image3");
                instagramFilterIntent.putExtra("Image3", files[2]);
            }

            initializeImages();
        }
    }

    private void initializeImages() {
        if (files[0] != null) {
            //Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).load(files[0]).into(preview1Img);

            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(files[0]);
            preview1Img.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

            if(editingImage.equalsIgnoreCase(files[0])) {
                preview1B.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }
        else {
            preview1Layout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            preview1B.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }

        if (files[1] != null) {
            //Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).load(files[1]).into(preview2Img);

            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(files[1]);
            preview2Img.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

            if(editingImage.equalsIgnoreCase(files[1])) {
                preview2B.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }
        else {
            preview2Layout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            preview2B.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }

        if (files[2] != null) {
            //Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).load(files[2]).into(preview3Img);

            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(files[2]);
            preview3Img.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

            if(editingImage.equalsIgnoreCase(files[2])){
                preview3B.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }
        else {
            preview3Layout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            preview3B.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    }

    public static void setBitmap(Bitmap originalImage) {
        ORIGINAL = originalImage;
    }

    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        // adding filter list fragment
        filtersListFragment = new FiltersListFragment();
        filtersListFragment.setInitiatedPESDK(initiated);
        filtersListFragment.setListener(this);

        // adding edit image fragment
        editImageFragment = new EditImageFragment();
        editImageFragment.setListener(this);

        adapter.addFragment(filtersListFragment, getString(R.string.tab_filters));
        adapter.addFragment(editImageFragment, getString(R.string.tab_edit));

        //filtersListFragment.prepareThumbnail(originalImage);

        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onFilterSelected(Filter filter, ImageFilter imageFilter) {
        // reset image controls
        resetControls();

        // applying the selected filter
        filteredImage = originalImage.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
        // preview filtered image
        if(filter!=null) {
            imagePreview.setImageBitmap(filter.processFilter(filteredImage));
        }else{
            imagePreview.setImageBitmap(imageFilter.renderImage(filteredImage,false));
        }
        finalImage = filteredImage.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
    }

    /**
     * Resets image edit controls to normal when new filter
     * is selected
     */
    private void resetControls() {
        if (editImageFragment != null) {
            editImageFragment.resetControls();
        }
        brightnessFinal = 10;
        saturationFinal = 1.0f;
        contrastFinal = 1.0f;
    }



    /**
     *  Image View click listners
     * */
    public void image1Click(View view) {
        if (!imgFile.toString().equalsIgnoreCase(files[0])) {
            saveImageToGallery();
            instagramFilterIntent.putExtra("image", files[0]);
            instagramFilterIntent.putExtra("PESDK",initiated);
            this.finish();
            startActivity(instagramFilterIntent);
            Toast.makeText(this, "lat"+latitude, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    public void image2Click(View view) {
        if (!imgFile.toString().equalsIgnoreCase(files[1])) {
            saveImageToGallery();
            instagramFilterIntent.putExtra("image", files[1]);
            instagramFilterIntent.putExtra("PESDK",initiated);
            this.finish();
            startActivity(instagramFilterIntent);
            Toast.makeText(this, "lat"+latitude, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    public void image3Click(View view) {
        if (!imgFile.toString().equalsIgnoreCase(files[2])) {
            saveImageToGallery();
            instagramFilterIntent.putExtra("image", files[2]);
            instagramFilterIntent.putExtra("PESDK",initiated);
            this.finish();
            startActivity(instagramFilterIntent);
            Toast.makeText(this, "lat"+latitude, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }



    class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
        private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

        public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
            super(manager);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return mFragmentList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mFragmentList.size();
        }

        public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
            mFragmentList.add(fragment);
            mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
        }
    }

    // load the default image from assets on app launch
    private void loadImage() {
        //@todo
        // originalImage = BitmapUtils.getBitmapFromGallery(this, Uri.parse(IMAGE_NAME), 300, 300);

        filteredImage = originalImage.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
        finalImage = originalImage.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);

        imagePreview.setImageBitmap(originalImage);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == SELECT_GALLERY_IMAGE) {

            Log.e("data.getData()", data.getData() + "");
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapUtils.getBitmapFromGallery(this, data.getData(), 800, 800);

            // clear bitmap memory
            originalImage.recycle();
            finalImage.recycle();
            finalImage.recycle();

            originalImage = bitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
            filteredImage = originalImage.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
            finalImage = originalImage.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
            imagePreview.setImageBitmap(originalImage);
            bitmap.recycle();

            // render selected image thumbnails
            filtersListFragment.prepareThumbnail(originalImage);
        }
    }


    /*
    * saves image to camera gallery
    * */
    private void saveImageToGallery() {
        Dexter.withActivity(this).withPermissions(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                .withListener(new MultiplePermissionsListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPermissionsChecked(MultiplePermissionsReport report) {
                        if (report.areAllPermissionsGranted()) {
                            if (originalFile.exists()) {
                                originalFile.delete();
                            }
                            // final String path = BitmapUtils.insertImage(getContentResolver(), finalImage, System.currentTimeMillis() + "_profile.jpg", null);
                            new MainActivity.SaveImageTask(finalImage, originalFile).execute();
                            //finish();
                        }
                        else {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Permissions are not granted!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onPermissionRationaleShouldBeShown(List<PermissionRequest> permissions, PermissionToken token) {
                        token.continuePermissionRequest();
                    }
                }).check();

    }

    private class SaveImageTask extends AsyncTask<byte[], Void, Void> {
        Bitmap finalBitmap;
        File name;

        public SaveImageTask(Bitmap finalBitmap, File name) {
            this.finalBitmap = finalBitmap;
            this.name = name;
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(byte[]... data) {
            FileOutputStream outStream = null;

            // Write to SD Card
            try {
                File file = name;
                if (file.exists()) {

                } else {
                    try {
                        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
                        finalBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
                        out.flush();
                        out.close();

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
            Log.e("FIlter MainACTIVITY", "SAVED");
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Image Saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }
    public void startingActivtity(){
        Intent chekInActivity = new Intent(MainActivity.this, CurrentLocationPlaces.class);

        if(files[0] != null) {
            chekInActivity.putExtra("Image1",files[0].toString());
        }
        if(files[1] != null) {
            chekInActivity.putExtra("Image2",files[1].toString());
        }
        if(files[2] != null) {
            chekInActivity.putExtra("Image3",files[2].toString());
        }
        chekInActivity.putExtra("source","gallery");
        chekInActivity.putExtra("Latitude", latitude);
        chekInActivity.putExtra("Longitude", longitude);
        startActivity(chekInActivity);
    }
}
```

May I know how to either stop restarting the activity and select the image to get its preview to apply filters or how to save the lat and long values so that it won't get reset when the activity restarts?

Answer (score 0):

If the value should be held across activity restarts you should be using an activity or shared preference.

Basically in your onCreate, load the values and assign them to your Textview (or other component). When they change just update the preference value.

```
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Load the lat/lng
        SharedPreferences preferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
        double lat = preferences.getDouble("latitude", 0);
        double lon = preferences.getDouble("longitude", 0);
 }
```

Then where you have your application update that value simply update the preference value.

```
 private void updatePreference(double lat, double lng) {
     SharedPreferences preferences = getPreference(MODE_PRIVATE);
     SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
     editor.putInt("latitude", lat);
     editor.putInt("longitude", lon);
     editor.commit();
 }
```

That will hold your values and allow you to update/interface with them across activity restarts.

SEE: [SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences)